# POWERPOINT - customize page numbering?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, character-styles, numbering

I was wondering if there's a way to number pages in Powerpoint using this style : "01, 02, 03..." instead of "1, 2, 3..."

Thanks a lot

Mey

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, mey, and with an interesting question... Powerpoint is a bit poor at field formatting level, and I haven't found references neither to insert the number of slides as a field nor to format the slide number field. Perhaps you can try to add a textbox with VBA and insert the formatted number... ;-)

Comment: Thanks Paolo! I suspected so....and I'm not familiar with VBA :) I added a text box with " PAGE # ", but my client doesn't want to insert the page number manually...so I guess I'll have to stay with a single-figure page numbering for now....

Thanks again!

Comment: In answer to a similar question elsewhere, I've just added a macro to my PPT FAQ page that will allow formatted numbering like this.  Custom numbering a presentation
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01282-Custom-numbering-a-presentation.htm

Answer (score 0):

Until Microsoft "fix" this rather obvious omission in PowerPoint, you can achieve this with an add-in found here:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00548_Slide_numbering_-_Slide_XX_of_YY.htm

You can also vote for the feature here:

https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/270149-powerpoint-online/suggestions/10957299-insert-slide-numbers